# How do labels work in multibib when using alpha style?

Tags: bibtex, multibib

When using multibib to separate bibliographies the labels help to show the reader where to find the actual bib entry. Sadly this does not seem to work with alpha style. The following minimal example shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{Math}{Math Readings}
\newcites{Phys}{Physics Readings}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\citeMath{paper3}
\citePhys{paper4}

\bibliographystyleMath{alpha}
\bibliographyMath{refs-etc}

\bibliographystylePhys{alpha}
\bibliographyPhys{refs-etc}

\end{document}
```

[image: Label Missing]

As you can see the labels are shown in the bibliography but not in the actual citations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multibib`'s `labeled` option does not work with the optional argument of `\bibitem` (as used heavily by `alpha.bst`). The following definition that also takes into account `\@bibitem` should make `labeled` support also the optional argument to `\bibitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}

\makeatletter
\def\newcites#1#2{%
  \def\@suffixlist{#1,}%
  \@for\@newrefname:=#2\do{%
    \mylop\@suffixlist\to\@suffix
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname refname\@suffix\endcsname
      {\@newrefname}%
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
      \expandafter\edef\csname @auxout\@suffix name\endcsname{\@suffix}%
      \begingroup
        \makeatletter
        \@input@{\csname @auxout\@suffix name\endcsname .aux}%
      \endgroup
      \immediate\openout\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
                        \csname @auxout\@suffix name\endcsname .aux
    \fi
    \@for\@citename:=\@mb@citenamelist\do{%
      \expandafter\edef\csname \@citename\@suffix\endcsname{%
        \let\noexpand\@citex\noexpand\mb@@citex
        \let\noexpand\@newciteauxhandle\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
        \noexpand\csname\@citename\endcsname}%
    }%
    \expandafter\edef\csname nocite\@suffix\endcsname##1{{%
      \let\noexpand\@auxout\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
      \noexpand\nocite{##1}}}%
    \iflabeled % if option labeled
      \expandafter\edef\csname @bibitem\@suffix\endcsname##1{%
        \noexpand\item
        \noexpand\if@filesw \noexpand\immediate\noexpand\write\noexpand\@auxout
        {\noexpand\string\noexpand\bibcite{##1}%
           {\@suffix\noexpand\the\noexpand\value{\noexpand\@listctr}}}%
        \noexpand\fi
        \noexpand\ignorespaces}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname @lbibitem\@suffix\endcsname[##1]##2{%
        \noexpand\item[\noexpand\@biblabel{##1}\noexpand\hfill]
        \noexpand\if@filesw \noexpand\immediate\noexpand\write\noexpand\@auxout
        {\noexpand\string\noexpand\bibcite{##2}{\@suffix##1}}%
        \noexpand\fi
        \noexpand\ignorespaces}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname @biblabel\@suffix\endcsname##1{[\@suffix##1]}%
    \fi % end if option labeled
    \expandafter\edef\csname bibliography\@suffix\endcsname##1{{%
      \let\noexpand\temp@auxout\noexpand\@auxout
      \let\noexpand\addtocontents\noexpand\mb@addtocontents
      \let\noexpand\@auxout\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
      \let\noexpand\jobname
         \expandafter\noexpand\csname @auxout\@suffix name\endcsname
      \let\noexpand\refname
          \expandafter\noexpand\csname refname\@suffix\endcsname
      \let\noexpand\bibname
          \expandafter\noexpand\csname refname\@suffix\endcsname
      \iflabeled
        \let\noexpand\@bibitem
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname @bibitem\@suffix\endcsname
        \let\noexpand\@lbibitem
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname @lbibitem\@suffix\endcsname
        \let\noexpand\@biblabel
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname @biblabel\@suffix\endcsname
      \fi
      \noexpand\bibliography{##1}%
      }}
    \expandafter\edef\csname bibliographystyle\@suffix\endcsname##1{%
      \noexpand\if@filesw
        \noexpand\immediate\noexpand\write\csname @auxout\@suffix\endcsname
          {\noexpand\string\noexpand\bibstyle{##1}}%
      \noexpand\fi}
   }%
}
\makeatother

\newcites{Math}{Math Readings}
\newcites{Phys}{Physics Readings}

\begin{document}
\citeMath{article-full}
\citePhys{incollection-full}

\bibliographystyleMath{alpha}
\bibliographyMath{xampl}

\bibliographystylePhys{alpha}
\bibliographyPhys{xampl}

\end{document}
```

[image: [MathAam86] [PhysLin77]]